# Not All Code Path Return Value in Func<> Generic Type Delegate

Tags: c#, generics

I am new Generic Type delegates and try implement **Func<> generic type delegate**

I am developing winform application in which I am try to save the file my save function returns me bool (True/False). i know its very simple to implement without the generic delegate but I want to implement into Generic Delegate my code

```
public bool Save( string fileName, SaveFlags options)
{
    if (fileName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        Func<string, SaveFlags, bool> func2 = (fileStream, opt) => Save(fs , options);
       **// what should I need to return**  
    }
}

private bool Save(Stream iStream, SaveFlags options)
{
   **//Some operation perform and return TRUE or FALSE**

}
```

I know whatever the last out parameter of Func<> its become the return type of Func<> i.e. it return by Func<>.

so how I can handle the Error **`"Not All Code Path Return Value"`**

Comment: Your code does not make sense.

Comment: Why use the generic Func at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up, you are looking at infinite recursion.  From your lambda parameter names, you intended to attach to the overload accepting a `Stream`.  But `Func<string, SaveFlags, bool>` means you're going to get the overload accepting a `string` instead.

Next, if your delegate takes parameters, you don't need to capture the parameters of the current function call.  So the lambda isn't helpful at all.

Taking that into account:

```
public bool Save( string fileName, SaveFlags options)
{
    if (fileName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
    Func<Stream, SaveFlags, bool> func2 = Save;
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        return func2(fs, options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Invoke your func.

```
public bool Save( string fileName, SaveFlags options)
{
    if (fileName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        Func<string, SaveFlags, bool> func2 = (fileStream, opt) => Save(fs , options);
        return func2(fileName, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code makes the code compile (as requested by the OP), but the usage of Func is pretty useless in this form.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your func2 with your parameters and returns its result.
You also need to repair you delegate.

```
Func<Stream, SaveFlags, bool> func2 = (fileStream, opt) => Save(fileStream, opt);
return func2(filename, options);
```

If you won't repair delegate, you would create func2 which takes two args and ignores them.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

```
 public bool Save(string fileName, SaveFlags options)
        {
            if (fileName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
            {
                Func<string, SaveFlags, bool> func2 = (fileStream, opt) => Save(fs, options);
                return func2(fileName, options);
            }
        }
```